# JQuery net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I am getting below error net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED,i am sending post to mu PHP,everything is on one PC.

```
function f() {
   var username = $("#user").val();
   var password = $("#pass").val();
   var payload = {"username":username,"password":password};
   var headers = new Headers({'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'});
   var request = $.post("http://localhost:8080/prosveta_projekat/ministarstvo/login.php",payload);
   request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
   request.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest");
   request.done(function () {
     var token =  headers.get("Authorization");
     localStorage.setItem("token",token);
   }).fail(function () {
     console.log("error");

   });
}
```

Comment: Guess port 8080 is not the port you were looking for..

Comment: Port it is,changed port from 8080 to 80.

Comment: Is it going to the same server where the page comes from? In that case you could try dropping the `http://localhost:8080` part and see if anything changes.

Answer (score 1):

May be your problem solved!

If not,

The problem is mainly occurs because of three issues.

1. May be you are trying to POST to `http://localhost:8080/` over network. That means POST from outside of that machine.

If so, that `localhost` by default discard those kind of requests. You have to check and allow it manually.

1. If not, try `timeout:15000` to stay trying to connect to `localhost:8080`, or `dataType: "jsonp"` in your ajax code.
2. Al last, check if Internet is connected or not.

Happy Coding!